# Method to insert CSV into mongo

Tags: mongodb, csv

Is there any method to insert CSV file into Mongo DB other than using mongoimport tool ? . I need to perform bulk insertions in mongoDB . I referred some sites and i found that there are some issues in using mongo import tool for importing large set of data.Please enlighten me how to insert CSV into mongoDB from application directly ? I need to know if there are any methods or wrappers in c++ or java for inserting CSV into MongoDB. Thanks in advance

Comment: After importing a CSV that isn't simply commas and fields, you should probably check it with something else.    I seem to recall having an issue with mongoimporting a CSV where odd things like more quotes or commas could be in fields.

Comment: @Paul Ya that i one kinda issue there are several issues there with mongoimport and thats why am asking is there any other way to import the csv into MongoDB

Comment: @WarriorPrince I suggest that you give us more detail about what you need to do or what languages are you using. Please update your question.

Comment: Why not just write the loop in your own code? It should be very simple.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bulk option available with mongo2.6

1. read the file
2. iterate and save to some variable
3. bulk.excecute.

> mongoimport -c 'check' --db 'test' --type csv --file test.csv  --headerline

use `mongoimport --help` for more help

(edit : `-h` option is for host)

### test.csv

name, age, sex
John, 23, M

Comment: the question was about "other than using mongoimport tool".

Answer (score 0):

the MongoDB shell is able to evaluate JavaScript. So you could write your own parser in JavaScript load your program into the shell and start it. If your don't like JavaScript, [there are a lot of drivers](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/) for other programming languages where you could load your file and use the driver to insert your data into the database.

Comment: Yes there are drivers but they may have a wrapper over mongo commands..am asking about the method to import CSV into MongoDb without using mongoimport or its wrapper.

Comment: Parse the CSV by your own written code and use the `collection.save()` operation to insert every CSV line by yourself. No need for mongoimport.

Comment: Thats quite inefficient.It takes too much time